# Prove given $f(x)$ integrable on $[a,b]$ then $g(x)=f(x-c)$ is integrable on $[a+c,b+c]$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

I've tried to prove that if $f(x)$ is an integrable function on $[a,b]$ then $g(x)=f(x-c)$ is integrable on $[a+c,b+c]$. I'm not sure about my way of proof so I would appreciate a lot your feedback.

So it goes this way:

- given f(x) is integrable in $[a,b]$, then for choosing every division $T$ and for every choosing of points $c_i$ in $[a,b]$, there exists a single finit $lim_{\Delta(T)\to 0} S_T(c_o,c_1,...,c_{n-1})$.
- now, if without loss of generality we split $[a+c,b+c]$ by devision $T'$ and $d_i\in[x_i,x_{i+1}]$ points in $T'$. then we'd like to test whether $\Sigma_{i=0}^{n-1}g(d_i)\Delta x_i$ exists and finit.
- but by mentioned before: $S_T(d_o,d_1,...,d_{n-1})=\Sigma_{i=0}^{n-1}g(d_i)\Delta x_i=\Sigma_{i=0}^{n-1}f(d_i-c)\Delta x_i$ and if we mark $c_i=d_i-c$ then $=\Sigma_{i=0}^{n-1}f(c_i)\Delta x_i$
- Let's notice that the mentioned sum is nonetheless $S_T(c_o,c_1,...,c_{n-1})$ noticed before for the integrable function $f$ in $[a,b]$.
- thus, finally, we get that the sum $\Sigma_{i=0}^{n-1}g(d_i)\Delta x_i$ also exists and finit and then $g(x)$ is integrable in $[a+c,b+c]$ as needed.

what do you think?

Comment: Your argument is correct but uses too many symbols. It is better to say that "to each Riemann sum $S$ of $f$ over partition $P$ of $[a, b]$ there is a corresponding Riemann sum $S'$ of $g(x) = f(x - c)$ over another partition $P'$ of $[a + c, b + c]$ such that $S' = S$ and vice-versa" Hence both the Riemann sums $S'$ and $S$ converge to same limit.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof looks fine.

Maybe you can think of $k(x)=x-c$ as a continuous monic function (linear Transformation) and go from there, less technically.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do this is to note that $f(x)=g(x+c)$ so,using the substitution $u=x+c$ we can write

$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx=\int_{a}^{b}g(x+c)dx=\int_{a+c}^{b+c}g(u)du=\int_{a+c}^{b+c}g(x)dx$ where the last equality is true because $u$ (or $x$ for that matter) is a dummy variable.

Comment: Yes, in the formal metter I know its a more short way to show it. But I was interested to know whether there are mistakes in the more conductive way of proof that I did.